# How to send attachment in e-mail in webform module in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

How can I receive attachment instead of link to file in e-mail in Drupal 7 WebForm?

Answer (score 2):

I used two modules [Mail System](http://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and [MIME MAIL](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) and configure my webform.